# Switching between universal & spa mode depending on query string?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt.js app that is set to universal mode, and deployed as a static website via `nuxt generate`. It is pulling data in via a GraphQL API that is connected to a CMS, and everything is working as it should. When the content is updated in the CMS a deploy script runs  `nuxt generate` and the updates show up on the website in a few seconds.

My problem is that the CMS (Craft CMS) has a live preview mode that is accessible when editing content. The preview window passes a token to the app, which can then modify its query based on the token value. This seems to work in spa mode, but not in universal mode. In universal mode, the query has already been run on the server when the static files were generated.

I've tried experimenting with a serverMiddleware based on the example [here](https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxt-dynamic-ssr-spa-handling/). I [forked the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-selectively-enable-ssr-or-spa-1z8jc?file=/pages/_.vue) and have tried every kind of logic inside the serverMiddleware function, nothing seems to produce any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nuxt 2.13](https://www.notion.so/Going-Full-Static-0633ab06d3d34d479947694d457a4817) has a preview mode that can be set via a plugin:

```
export default async function ({ query, enablePreview }) => {
  if (query.preview) {
    enablePreview()
  }
}
```

When enablePreview() is set, the page will query the live API rather than using the generated page.

Comment: enablePreview() only works when the route changes. Even on page refresh the asyncData calls are not made.

Comment: I am using a version of this code on multiple sites. If the condition matches, enablePreview() is run and asyncData calls are made. 

Comment: You can also do things like this in your components:
```mounted () {
    if ($nuxt.isPreview) {
      //your preview code here
    }
  }```